# Insert NOPs at odd offsets in FASM

Tags: optimization, assembly, fasm

In older assemblers, there existed a preprocessor instruction ".even" or "even", which insert a NOP, if the current offset is odd, so that the offset of the next instruction/variable will be even. Does a similar instruction exist in FASM? Isn't it important anymore to place words at even offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment is still important, look at the "align" directive.

align 4;

e.g. will align the next instruction (or part of a data structure) at a 4byte boundary.